# Upgrading my android maps using Android Google Map API v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Till now I was using Android Google Map API v1 for displaying maps and user location (a marker in map with circle).

Now planning to upgrade Android Google Map API from v1 to v2. In this, can anyone please suggest me on the following items:

- We will use mapView.invalidate() to refresh map view in version1. Whats the method we can use for version2.
- In version1, to zoom and animateTo we will use the following code like:

  aMapController = itsMapView.getController();

  aMapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs( aMinLatitude - aMaxLatitude ), Math.abs( aMinLongitude - aMaxLongitude ));

  aMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((aMaxLatitude + aMinLatitude)/2 - 100, (aMaxLongitude + aMinLongitude)/2));

How can we perform zoom and animateTo options in version2?

Can anyone please guide me.

Thank You.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views?hl=pl 
Check Developer Guide->Changing the View tab, Doc with good sample. 
It should help you.

Comment: Thanks Pawel Cala. I will check this!

Comment: The following link may be useful for the new developers like me:
http://mobisys.in/blog/2013/04/google-maps-android-api-v2-different-operations/

Comment: Step by step Android Map Migrate tutorial from v1 to v2 : http://geekonjava.blogspot.com/2015/06/migrating-from-v1-maps-to-v2-maps-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former MapView is now a GoogleMap.
For zoom and animateTo check out the CameraPosition class, it's used all over the new API.

Here's an example that zooms to level 6 and animatesTo somewhere

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(51.163361, 10.447683)).zoom(6).build();
    gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

`gmap` is the GoogleMap object.

Unfortunately I haven't found a zoomToSpan method, but implementations can be found on SO.

I would advise you to just try it out and read up on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).